# Add vectors to Gimp, like brushes and fonts?

Tags: gimp

I downloaded many folders with decorative elements within them, mainly with files ending with .ems. I want to add them into my GIMP software but where do I add them?

There is a folder for adding fonts for instance, and also one for brushes, but I do not have a clue where I'd add these new folders.

**Is there a folder within my Gimp directory where I can add vector or raster art, such as decorative elements, so I have easy access to them just like with fonts and brushes?**

Comment: Hi @Tim. I've edited your question considerably. Please refrain from using links that do not contribute to the question, they make your question appear spammy, especially when used in the title. Also, the site you mentioned features a lot of pirated and stolen content, beware of using it in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not add images to Gimp, regardless of being vector or raster. Photoshop has a library function, but Gimp does not. Keep the folder with files wherever you want to and just open the image you want to use in Gimp.

Fonts and brushes are different to images, in that you never use them alone. In the case of decorative elements, this is an edge case. You might consider transforming the ones you're going to use most to a brush.

Beware though that having many brushes and fonts will slow down Gimp considerably.

As a side note: I'm not even sure Gimp can open .ems files as these are CAD/CAM files.

Comment: I do appreciate your excellent response. I understand more now. most grateful